# Draw an array with Google Drawings

Tags: google-drawings

I read in [a reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4eecpl/brian_kernighan_on_the_typesetting_of_the_go/?ref=share&ref_source=link) that Brian and Alan used [Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings) to create the drawings in [The Go Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0134190440). 
I'd like to learn how easily to draw an array like the one shown below:

[image]

It's easy enough to draw a rectangle, but is there a quick way to tell Google Drawings how to create a rectangle with a series of evenly spaced lines?

Or to take a different approach, create a row or column of repeated boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the *table*. From the help (which isn't linkable):

1. Open a document or a slide in a presentation.
2. Click Table and then Insert table.
3. Click to choose how many rows and columns you want to add. Tables can be as large as 20 x 20 cells.
4. The table will be added to your document.

Now you can create a `14x1` or `1x2` table:

[image]
[image]

For those interested this is a quick attempt using the `Ubuntu` font:

[image]